# Django: Display inline through direct relation

Tags: django, django-admin

I have models:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    employee_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, db_index=True)
    position = models.ForeignKey(
        'orgunits.Position',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='employees'
    )


class Position(models.Model):
    orgunit = models.ForeignKey(
        OrgUnit,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name=_('orgunit'),
        related_name='positions',
    )
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=255)


class OrgUnit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=255)
    type = models.CharField(_('type'), max_length=55)
    address = models.TextField(_('address'), null=True, blank=True)
```

I would like to display all CustomUser instances assigned to OrgUnit THROUGH Position:

```
class OrgUnitEmployeesInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = CustomUser


class OrgUnitAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = OrgUnit
    inlines = OrgUnitEmployeesInline,
```

But of course there is an error:

> <class 'orgunits.admin.OrgUnitEmployeesInline'>: (admin.E202)
> 'authentication.CustomUser' has no ForeignKey to 'orgunits.OrgUnit'.

because `Position` has ForeignKey to 'orgunits.OrgUnit'.

Also I tried this:

```
class OrgUnitEmployeesInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = CustomUser
    fk_name = 'position'
```

but error:

> <class 'orgunits.admin.OrgUnitEmployeesInline'>: (admin.E202) fk_name
> 'position' is not a ForeignKey to 'orgunits.OrgUnit'.

How can I display users in orgunits inline?

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing in simple way is this:

```
class OrgUnitEmployeesInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Position
    fk_name = 'positions'
    fields = ('employees', )
```

Otherwise you have to settle with custom forms.

Comment: I cannot change models. I need to do this through Position model

Comment: You ask `I would like to display all CustomUser instances assigned to OrgUnit:`, but you don't have direct relation from User to OrgUnit. If you cannot change models, then you cannot do that directly.

Comment: Ok, I added "THROUGH Position"

Comment: I don't think it's achievable in the way you want to. I've edited my answer to much closer option.